# Issue with clipped raster location

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, google-earth

I tried to clip a USGS GMTED2010 elevation data raster in order to match it with a raster I clipped from the Google Earth satellite. However, when I run the command, the output raster appears in different location with different co-ordinates.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works